# provision ec2 in autoscaling group with ansible unsing cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I created autoscaling group which launch EC2 which has ELB. My question is how to provision those EC2 instances with ansible? 
Before I used CNAME, but now I cant get instance dns. Please correct me if I wrong.

Should I use dynamic inventory or are there any other options?

My cloud formation template below:

```

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
 "Description" : "Template create autoscaling group",
  "Parameters": {
   "devKeyPair": {
  "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
  "Default" : "dev-key"

}
},
"Resources" : {
"LaunchConfig" : {
"Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
"Properties" : {
  "KeyName" : { "Ref": "devKeyPair" },
  "ImageId" : "ami-1effc703",
   "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
  "#!/bin/bash\n", "\n", "    echo 'Installing Git'\n","    yum --nogpgcheck -y install wget\n""] ]}},
  "InstanceType" : "t2.small",
  "BlockDeviceMappings" : [
     {
       "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
       "Ebs" : { 
          "VolumeSize" : "10", 
          "VolumeType" : "gp2", 
          "DeleteOnTermination" : "true"
          } 
     }
  ]
 }
 },
"BackendGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "AvailabilityZones" : ["eu-central-1a"],
  "MinSize" : "1",
  "MaxSize" : "1",
  "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
  "LoadBalancerNames" : [ { "Ref" : "ElasticLoadBalancer" } ],
  "Tags": [
    {
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
        "ResourceId": "bas-auto",
        "Value": "bas-dev",
        "Key": "Name",
        "PropagateAtLaunch" : "true"
    }
]
  }
},

"ElasticLoadBalancer": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties": {
  "AvailabilityZones": ["eu-central-1a"],
    "Listeners": [ {
      "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
      "InstancePort": "80",
      "Protocol": "HTTP"
    } ]
  }
},
"BackendDNS" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneName" : "example.com.",
    "Comment" : "Targered to Bas instance",
    "RecordSets" : [{
      "Name" : "bas-dev.example.com.",
      "Type" : "CNAME",
      "TTL" : "300",
      "ResourceRecords" :  [
        {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ElasticLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
},
}
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to provision your VM *before* starting the new instance. I.e. make sure that the image you're starting the ASG instances from is already provisioned. 
One way to do this is to use something like [packer.io](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html) to create a new AMI using Ansible as your provisioner. Then you can simply pass this new AMI ID into the `ImageId` attribute of the LaunchConfiguration.

Another approach could involve using the `User Data` to "phone home" and tell you the public IP address the instance has acquired.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was install Ansible Tower with a free license, the use user_data:  properties ansible have an example here. https://www.ansible.com/blog/autoscaling-infrastructures

But is necessary build a first base  image because if you NOT do this extend all provisioning time delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Opswork with Cloudformation in order to run Ansible whenever a new instance is added to the Autoscaling group.

Though Opswork uses Chef but you can use this custom cookbook https://github.com/deepakagg/ansible-opsworks which will run desired playbook.